# Number of binary trees of size $n$ such that all subtrees of same size are equal?

Tags: trees, combinatorics, binary-trees

In the following, I consider rooted, unlabelled, ordered binary trees, where each node has exactly $0$ or $2$ children (I will simply call them binary trees). A binary tree $t'$ is a subtree of a binary tree $t$ if there exists a node $v$ in $t$ such that the tree rooted at this node $v$ equals $t'$.

For a binary tree $t$, let the size $|t|$ be the number of leaves of $t$, i.e. the number of nodes that have zero children.

I am interested in the following property of a binary tree $t$:
If two subtrees $t'$ and $t''$ of $t$ have the same size, i.e. $|t'|=|t''|$, then the subtrees have to be equal, i.e. $t'=t''$.
In other words, the number of different subtrees of $t$ that have size $m$ is at most one for each $m$.

**Question**: What I want to know is the number of different trees of size $n$ fulfilling this property?

I tried some of the usual combinatorial approaches but I made no progress so far.

Comment: Interesting problem?   What are your thoughts so far?  Have you made any progress?  For instance, have you tried counting the number of such trees of size $n$, for small numbers of $n$?  (A program might help.)  Have you tried plugging that sequence into [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)?

Comment: I don't think it's in OEIS. Anyone want to double-check $1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 40, 120, 357$ for $0 \le n \le 7$?

Comment: @D.W. Unfortunately no progress so far, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: I did not check for an OEIS sequence so far since I thought it might be possible that this problem is known and somebody can tell me the solution quite fast here. So thanks to @Peter Taylor for checking.

Comment: The tree nodes are not labeled, right? And a tree with 1 left child and a tree with 1 right child are considered the same?

Comment: I take it that by "binary tree", you mean a *rooted* binary tree in which each vertex has degree 3? By "subtree", do you mean "a subgraph that is a tree" (the usual graph theory interpretation) or "a tree that consists of some vertex and all descendants of that vertex", or something else?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I can build only 3 trees with 4 nodes, how do you get 5, maybe we are solving instance with different interpretations. My trees rooted at 1: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]; [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]; [(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4)]. Notice that I don't care about labels, used only to write the tree.

Comment: @6005 I am interested in unlabelled, ordered binary trees, where nodes have exactly zero or two children (but I think if you can solve one setting, then you can probably solve the other one as well)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I mean rooted, ordered, unlabelled binary trees, where each node has exactly 0 or 2 children. I clarified that in the question. A tree $t'$ is a subtree of $t$ if there is a node $v$ of the tree $t$ such that the tree rooted at this node $v$ equals $t'$, so "a tree that consists of some vertex and all descendants of that vertex".

Comment: @Danny Thanks for the clarification. One more thing: are two trees equal if they are isomorphic as rooted graphs (i.e. up to reordering of left and right children)? Or are they equal if the left child equals the left child, and the right child equals the right child?

Comment: @6005 I consider ordered binary trees, i.e. we distinguish between the left and the right child of a node.